# scikit-learn FeatureUnion gridsearch over subsets of features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can I use a FeatureUnion in scikit learn, so that the Gridsearch can treat its parts optionally?

The code below works and sets up a FeatureUnion with a TfidfVectorizer for words and a TfidfVectorizer for chars.

When doing a Gridsearch, in addition to testing the defined parameter space, I would also like to test only 'vect__wordvect' with its ngram_range parameter (without there being a TfidfVectorizer for the chars), and also only 'vect__lettervect' with the lowercase parameter True and False, the other TfidfVectorizer being disabled.

EDIT: Complete code example based on maxymoo suggestion.

How can this be done?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

# setup the featureunion
wordvect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word')
lettervect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char')
featureunionvect = FeatureUnion([("lettervect", lettervect), ("wordvect", wordvect)])

# setup the pipeline
classifier = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', featureunionvect), ('classifier', classifier)])

# gridsearch parameters 
parameters = {
            'vect__wordvect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],  # commenting out these two lines
            'vect__lettervect__lowercase': [True, False],     # runs, but there is no parameterization anymore
            'vect__transformer_list': [[('wordvect', wordvect)],
                                        [('lettervect', lettervect)],
                                        [('wordvect', wordvect), ('lettervect', lettervect)]]}
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)

# data
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])

# gridsearch CV
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(newsgroups_train.data, newsgroups_train.target)
for score in gs_clf.grid_scores_:
    print "gridsearch scores: ", score
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FeatureUnion` has a parameter called `transformer_list` that you could use to grid-search over; so in your case your grid search parameters would become

```
parameters = {'vect__wordvect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
              'vect__lettervect__lowercase': [True, False],
              'vect__transformer_weights': [{"lettervect":1,"wordvect":0}, 
                                            {"lettervect":0,"wordvect":1}, 
                                            {"lettervect":1,"wordvect":1}]}
```

Comment: There is a ' missing after vect__transformer_list. Even after fixing it, I get:     'vect__transformer_list': [[('wordvec':wordvec)],
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The documentation on transformer_list is quite sparse, I do not understand how to fix/adjust your code on scikit learn 0.17.1

Comment: sorry there were a lot of weird typos in my answer, i've fixed it up, does it work now?

Comment: there's nothing mysterious about transformser_list, it's just overriding the main argument of the FeatureUnion

Comment: I made changes to the code to give a complete example. It only works if I also comment out all featureunion parameters, but with the parameters I get: ValueError: Invalid parameter wordvect for estimator FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1,
       transformer_list=[('lettervect', [...] Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

Comment: ah ok, do you see what was going wroing?  i've rewritten using transformer weights, it's working now, and is a cleaner solution anyway.

Comment: @maxymoo Your post helped me quite a bit in solving something similar, but I had a little snag I suppose I ought to mention: I were getting errors about 'list' not having a field 'get', and from reading docs figured out it should be using structs instead.`'vect__transformer_weights': [{"lettervect":1,"wordvect":0}, {"lettervect":0,"wordvect":1}, {"lettervect":1,"wordvect":1}]`